# Scala Databinder Dispatch: recover Http response body when code is not 2XX

Tags: scala

When handling dispatch 0.11.2 calls using `OK`, an `Exception` is returned in case the HTTP response code is not in the 2XX range. That behaviour is fixed in the `OKHandler`.

Unfortunately the message of the exception only contains information about the status code. A Typical message would be: `Unexpected Response status: 400`.

Is there a simple way of recovering the body of the response (which in my case is a JSON containing data about the error) ?
Is there an alternative to `OK` ?

Typical handling code

```
Http( myReq OK as.String ) onComplete {

    case Success( resp ) =>
        //do something with the string resp

    case Failure( e ) =>
        //unfortunately the exception `e` does not provide access to the response body
}
```

Comment: what about write your own custom handler, similar to OkHandler, but instead return full response, not the StatusCode only

Comment: @Mysterion I would very much prefer using a mechanism provided by the dispatch library itself or in an existing extension and not having to maintain it

Comment: agree, but it looks like Dispatch couldn't do that right now

Comment: You can use `Http(myReq > as.String)` to get the body regardless of the status, or just `Http(myReq)` for the raw response.